# Order by for SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a SQL Server column with the following values:

```
PPPX-31
CDGH-3
CDHUI-2
DFGTT-20
CUIT-18
AXDDX-32
```

How can I order by based on last digits in rows of given column?

regards
Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the rows contains the multiple hyphens solved by using the below query

SELECT * FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX( '-', REVERSE( MyColumn ) + '-' ) - 1))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY RIGHT(MyColumn, 1)
```

for the last character or:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY REVERSE(MyColumn)
```

To order by the reversed string.

Comment: Not working reversing causing 2 as 20 and 20 as 2 for row data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one `-` in the string and string after `-` is numeric.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(YourCol, CHARINDEX('-',YourCol) + 1, LEN(YourCol))
```

If you need numeric ordering, `convert()` the string into `INT`

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, 
             SUBSTRING(YourCol, CHARINDEX('-',YourCol) + 1, LEN(YourCol)))
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b5e6/1)**

Results (numeric ordering):

```
|  YOURCOL |
|----------|
|  CDHUI-2 |
|   CDGH-3 |
|  CUIT-18 |
| DFGTT-20 |
|  PPPX-31 |
| AXDDX-32 |
```

Comment: My column data may have multiple hyphens.